# identify similar meshes in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, graphics

I was trying to identify the meshes which are similar. I did able to check this by comparing triangles and vertices, but i also want to compare  dimensions of 2 meshes. how to do this ?
bounding box didn't work.
is there any way to achieving this using OBB ?

Comment: What you exactly mean by comparing dimensions? Can you describe it more specific?

Comment: @VítZadina i am trying to compare diagonal lengths of bounding boxes of 2 meshes, which is one of the parameters of similarity. as bounding box is axis aligned, diagonal length is getting affected by the orientation of the meshes

Comment: @chitanya OBB can help you with this. My first idea was remove rotation on hiearhy before checking similarity, but I think you working with similarity of vertices. So OBB can help you, because it will provide you better information. But if two objects have same OBB, you can't say there are same. They only have same OBB.